# when creating new users, nothings shows on dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

a user is created in the admin panel, and it shows total stores, total products and so on.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwi0n.jpg)

When i create a new user for login, nothings shows on dashboard panel. no total store, no total products and so on...

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjlvZ.jpg)

```html
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Dashboard
        <small>Control panel</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
      <?php if($is_admin == true): ?>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
              <div class="inner">
                <h3><?php echo $total_products ?></h3>

                <p>Total Products</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
              </div>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url('products/') ?>" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ./col -->
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-green">
              <div class="inner">
                <h3><?php echo $total_paid_orders ?></h3>

                <p>Total Paid Orders</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
              </div>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url('orders/') ?>" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ./col -->
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
              <div class="inner">
                <h3><?php echo $total_users; ?></h3>

                <p>Total Users</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-android-people"></i>
              </div>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url('users/') ?>" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ./col -->
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-red">
              <div class="inner">
                <h3><?php echo $total_stores ?></h3>

                <p>Total Stores</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-android-home"></i>
              </div>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url('stores/') ?>" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ./col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      <?php endif; ?>
      

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dashboardMainMenu").addClass('active');
    }); 
  </script>
```

This is the code of the dashboard cpanel...

---

THIS CODE IS FOR CREATING NEW USER

```html
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Manage
        <small>Users</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Users</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
          
          <?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
            </div>
          <?php elseif($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Add User</h3>
            </div>
            <form role="form" action="<?php base_url('users/create') ?>" method="post">
              <div class="box-body">

                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="groups">Groups</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="groups" name="groups">
                    <option value="">Select Groups</option>
                    <?php foreach ($group_data as $k => $v): ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>"><?php echo $v['group_name'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="cpassword">Confirm password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="fname">First name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First name" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lname">Last name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                  <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="1">
                      Male
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="2">
                      Female
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->

              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('users/') ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Back</a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- col-md-12 -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
      

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#groups").select2();

    $("#mainUserNav").addClass('active');
    $("#createUserNav").addClass('active');
  
  });
</script>
```

Can someone help me and tell me what is the problem?

Comment: This is where the issue is `<?php if($is_admin == true): ?>` Check to be sure if the new user is an admin based on this check you have here. Most likely the variable $is_admin is false or doesn't exist when you create the new or when you log in.

Comment: yeah, the varibale $is_admin does not exist in the code

Comment: does that solve the problem??

Comment: @RotimiBest i have putted the add new user code, and tell me what should i add...

Comment: When you submit your form I don't see any field that indicates if the person is an admin or not. I see your form redirects to this page `<?php base_url('users/create') ?>` there should be a method that handles the form request there and if you want that user to be an admin you need to return an extra variable `$is_admin` and make it true so that user can see the dashboard. BTW what is this check for `<?php if($is_admin == true): ?>`?

Comment: @RotimiBest i made it is_admin == false and the those are shown now when i create a new users...

Comment: why did you need that field in the first place if I may ask `is_admin`?

Comment: @RotimiBest the code is not mine, and im not to good with php thats why i asked for help... I dont know why is there is_admin

Comment: Okay I understand, I have been in that similar situation when I asked my first question on stackoverflow. Understanding the code before just using it is very important if you want to improve your programming skills. Please accept the answer (I just posted it) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the check for `<?php if($is_admin == true): ?>` and this would display the content you want to see.

To continue from what you said in the comment:

> @RotimiBest the code is not mine, and im not to good with php thats why i asked for help... I dont know why is there is_admin

I asked you that question, to understand why it was there. I guess the author of the code was trying to prevent those that are not administrators from viewing the total stores, total products and so on. And if you don't need that then you should remove that check.

Note: There might be cases where you would need to hide certain parts of your application from non-administrators in this case that if statement would be good. To implement this in your database you should have a field called `is_admin` and you should make it a `Boolean` meaning true or false which you can set manually and then when a user logs in, you should check for that field when you return the whole fields of that particular user from the user table.

The explanation might not make sense if you don't get grounded in php and mysql, I suggest you take this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJbfyzaA2QA&list=PLillGF-Rfqbap2IB6ZS4BBBcYPagAjpjn). It really covers the basics to a comfortable understanding of the language.

I hope this helps )

[@rotimi_best](https://twitter.com/rotimi_best)